# Angular 4 - route value not acessible

Tags: angular, typescript, routes

I have a service that gets a list of routes, to sites, which is used to build a Bootstrap 4 drop down menu using the code below.

The challenge I have is I cannot figure out how to capture the route value and insert it into the links for "home" and "details". Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```js
import { Component, Injectable, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { sitesService } from '../services/sites.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.css']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {

  sites: any;
  filteredsiteTitle = '';
  selectedsite: { name: string };
  // selectedsite: any;
  constructor(private sitesService: sitesService, private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    // All sites
    this.sitesService.getsites().subscribe(
      (response) => this.updatesites(response),
      (error) => console.log(error)
    );
    // Selected site
    this.selectedsite = {
      name: this.route.snapshot.params['name']
    };
    this.route.params.subscribe(
        (params: Params) => {
            this.selectedsite.name = params['name'];
            console.log(params);
            return this.selectedsite.name;
        }
    );
  }

  updatesites(sitesResponse) {
    this.sites = sitesResponse;
    this.sites = JSON.parse(this.sites._body);
  }

}

HTML Template code is:
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-inverse fixed-top bg-inverse">
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse" aria-controls="navbarCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
      <span class="navbar-brand-heavy">DEMO</span><span class="navbar-brand-light">sites</span> {{selectedSite.name}}
    </a>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse" *ngIf="sites">
      <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle selectedSite" href="#" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{selectedSite.name}}</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="sites dropdown" id="sitesdropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-item">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="filteredSites">
            </a>
            <a *ngFor="let site of sites" 
              class="dropdown-item" 
              [routerLink]="['/home', site.Title]"
              >
              {{ site.Title }}
            </a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/home', 'selectedSite']">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]="['/details', selectedSite.name]">Details</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="form-inline mt-2 mt-md-0">
        <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search">
      </form>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

try
`this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('name')`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17577206)

Comment: Not sure what you on about? Question is how to capture the route value, my answer shows how.

Comment: This doesn't work. It looks like ngOnit() fires once and never again so I don't seem to be able to get the route value. Can you provide a more clear example?